# Ecapture Module Not installing in Python 3.9.1

Tags: image-capture

### I am not able to download ecapture module trying with python 3.9.1 error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

ERROR: Failed building wheel for scikit-image
Failed to build scikit-image
ERROR: Could not build wheels for scikit-image which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Answer (score 0):

From what I have seen, scikit does not support Python 3.9 (in Pypi) yet. Try using an older version (like python 3.7).
You can, however, install it for python 3.9 using conda install -c conda-forge scikit-learn (if you are using anaconda).

I got this information from https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/18852